# read and write to application stream

Tags: windows, vb.net, process, arm, segger-jlink

I am trying to write to and read from a command line interface to operate debugger tools but I am having trouble with process streams.

We have a new product at work that has 2 microprocessors (Microchip and Freescale Arm M4) that need to get programmed during production.  We are using an ICD3 debugger to program the Microchip PIC and a JLink Ultra+ to program the Freescale chip and a custom designed tool to manipulate the board and put it in the correct states for programming.

I found that both debugger tools have a command line interface (looks just like Windows Command Prompt).  Using:

```
process.start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v3.25\mplab_ipe\ipecmd.exe", "-F" + PIC350HEXFilePath + " -M -P18F46J11 -TPICD3")
```

I can run the ICD3 debugger and successfully program the Microchip PIC.  However, I cannot seem to get the JLink command line interface to accept multiple commands.  Thus I want to pass a single command, read the output from the command line and pass the next command.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    'handles data from stream of jlinkProcess
Private Sub jlinkProcessDataHandler(sendingProcess As Object, outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim data_read As String

    data_read = outLine.Data

    rtxtboxStatusText(vbNewLine + outLine.Data)

    If data_read = "J-Link>Unknown command. '?' for help." Then

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnK70program_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnK70program.Click
    btnLoadCurrentTimeEnable(True)

    jlinkProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False          
    jlinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True    
    jlinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True     

    jlinkProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SEGGER\JLink_V512e\JLink.exe"
    jlinkProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-device MK70FN1M0xxx15"
    jlinkProcess.Start()


    jlinkProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()

End Sub
```

It works for reading when RedirectStandardInput is false.  Of course when its false any code I try to write to the input stream throws an error.  When True, the handler never executes and I cannot read anything. Any advice on how to read from and write to an application? Thanks.